# How do I zip a file with codename one zipme?

Tags: codenameone

Can anyone provide a sample code to zip a file in codename one with zipme?
I checked the sample on zipme webpage but only have the unzip sample code.
[zipme project](https://github.com/codenameone/ZipSupport)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this but I guess it would look pretty close to this:

```
try(ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(destinationOutputStream)) {
  output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("NameOfFileInZip"));
  output.write(byteArrayContentOfFileInZip); 
}
```

Check out `ZipOutputStream` samples for further guidance. Should be pretty similar to standard JavaSE only with different packages and more limited API.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a procedure to zip a file. But I can't unzip the zip file by 7-zip.

```
    public static void zipFile(String zipFile, String srcFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream i = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(srcFile);
    OutputStream o = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(zipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(o);
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile));
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ((len = i.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```